# How can I find a generic child in a non-generic list in swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm having some problems with swift generics.

The following code compiles just fine, but the line `if let item = row as? SelectionInputControl<Any> {` doesn't work like I imagined it would.

I have a subclass of `BasicInputView`, let's call it `CountryInputView` which puts an `SelectionInputControl<Country>` (`Country` is an `enum` in this case) object into `rows`, but neither does `SelectionInputControl<Country>` resolve to `SelectionInputControl<Any>` nor can I use `SelectionInputControl` (because that won't compile).

How can I do fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class BasicInputView: UIView {

    var popoverPresenter: (UIViewController & UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate)? {
        didSet {
            for row in rows {
                if let item = row as? SelectionInputControl<Any> {
                    item.popoverPresenter = popoverPresenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private var rows = [BasicInputControl]()
}

class SelectionInputControl<T>: BasicInputControl {

    var enumValues = [T]()
    private var currentValue: T?

    var popoverPresenter: (UIViewController & UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate)?

}
```

Comment: In `class SelectionInputControl<T> { }` shouldn't you specify the type to that of your enum such as `class SelectionInputControl<T: RawRepresentable> where T.RawValue == Int { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast `SelectionInputControl<Country>` to `SelectionInputControl<Any>` because generics in Swift are not variant, except for arrays. :(

One way is to introduce another protocol, `PopoverPresentable`:

```
protocol PopoverPresentable {
    var popoverPresenter: (UIViewController & UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate)? { get set }
}
```

Conform `SelectionInputControl` to this protocol:

```
extension SelectionInputControl : PopoverPresentable {}
```

Now you can cast to `PopoverPresentable` instead:

```
if let item = row as? PopoverPresentable {
    item.popoverPresenter = popoverPresenter
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. However, you should maybe replace `extension SelectionInputControl : PopoverPresentable {}` with `class SelectionInputControl<T>: BasicInputControl, PopoverPresentable`, because extensions on generic classes don't work.

Comment: My bad. I was confusing it with extensions not being allowed with @objc protocols :-/